# OpenGL streching up geometry

Tags: opengl, rendering, models

I'm developping my own game engine in C++/OpenGL 3 but I've got some troubles with my geometry. Indeed, when I render something everything is weirdly streched up :
[image: Opengl steched image]

By tweaking scale values we can see what it should render :
[image: OpenGL not streched up]

I don't know what to do, I've checked each matrices at least 100 times. If you have any idea it would be great for me !

Edit: As recommended in the comments, I add some rendering-related code which can be helpful !

Mesh loading, bufferizing and rendering :

```c
void RD_Mesh::loadMesh(std::string filepath) {
    BD_Reader* reader = new BD_Reader();

    reader->ClearAll();
    reader->ReadMSHFile(filepath);

    for (int i = 0; i < reader->GetVerticesCount(); i++) {
        RAWvertices.push_back(reader->GetVertexByIndex(i).getX());
        RAWvertices.push_back(reader->GetVertexByIndex(i).getY());
        RAWvertices.push_back(reader->GetVertexByIndex(i).getZ());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < reader->GetIndicesCount(); i++) {
        RAWindices.push_back(reader->GetIndiceByIndex(i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < reader->GetNormalCount(); i++) {
        RAWnormals.push_back(reader->GetNormalByIndex(i).getX());
        RAWnormals.push_back(reader->GetNormalByIndex(i).getY());
        RAWnormals.push_back(reader->GetNormalByIndex(i).getZ());
    }

    Bufferize();

    delete reader;
}

void RD_Mesh::render() {
    //m_shader->useShader();
    m_mat->BindMaterial();

    glm::mat4 mdl = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    //Position
    mdl = glm::translate(mdl, glm::vec3(m_position.getX(), m_position.getY(), m_position.getZ()));

    //Scale
    mdl = glm::scale(mdl, glm::vec3(m_scale.getX(), m_scale.getY(), m_scale.getZ()));

    //Rotation
    mdl = glm::rotate(mdl, glm::radians(m_rotation.getX()), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    mdl = glm::rotate(mdl, glm::radians(m_rotation.getY()), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    mdl = glm::rotate(mdl, glm::radians(m_rotation.getZ()), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    m_shader->SetMatrix("model", mdl);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, RAWindices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void RD_Mesh::Bufferize() {
    std::vector<float> MIXvertNorm;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < RAWvertices.size()) {
        //Vertices

        MIXvertNorm.push_back(RAWvertices[i]); //Write

        i++; //Increment

        MIXvertNorm.push_back(RAWvertices[i]); //Same Pattern

        i++;

        MIXvertNorm.push_back(RAWvertices[i]); //Same Pattern

        i++;

        i -= 3; //Resetting i

        //Normals

        MIXvertNorm.push_back(RAWnormals[i]); //Write

        i++; //Increment

        MIXvertNorm.push_back(RAWnormals[i]); //Same Pattern

        i++;

        MIXvertNorm.push_back(RAWnormals[i]); //Same Pattern

        i++;
    }

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, MIXvertNorm.size() * sizeof(float), &MIXvertNorm[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, RAWindices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &RAWindices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //Vertices
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    //Normals
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
}
```

Camera set-up :

```c
void RD_Camera::SetupCamera() {
    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(FOV), (float)m_rndr->getWindowWidth() / m_rndr->getWindowHeigh(), m_near, m_far); //Projection matrix
    view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(m_pos.getX(), m_pos.getY(), m_pos.getZ()), glm::vec3(m_subject.getX(), m_subject.getY(), m_subject.getZ()), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)); //View matrix

    m_shader->SetMatrix("projection", projection);
    m_shader->SetMatrix("view", view);
    m_shader->SetVec3("CamPos", m_pos);
}
```

(notice that every matrices are all `glm::mat4`)-

Comment: Homogeneous coordinates? i.e. check the last row/column, it should read 0,0,0,1. If the last value in your 4x4 matrix is not 1, you may get all sorts of funkiness.

Comment: If you want help fixing the code that draws these images, you should show us that code. Boil it down to a minimal complete verifiable example: the smallest snippet we could use to reproduce the problem in a new project.

Comment: Also show the View and Projection matrices.